# powershell removing a specific registry key

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell and I am trying to remove a specific value from the run registry key.  I am using the `remove-item` command, however, I don't see a switch to specify a single value. I don't want to remove the entire key, just one value.

For reference the batch equivalent of what I am trying to do:

```
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v SunJavaUpdateSched /f
```

Comment: You are trying to remove a registry value, not a registry key :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the cmdlet `remove-itemproperty`

Answer (score 20):

**Remove-ItemProperty -Name 'nameofkeyentry' -Path 'pathtothekey'**

For example the key 'HKCU:\Accessibility\AudioDescription' has 3 values

---

```
(Default) REG_SZ (value not set)
Locale    REG_SZ [blank]
On        REG_SZ 0
```

---

Suppose we would like to remove the 3rd value 'On' - we would do so as follows

**Remove-ItemProperty -Name 'On' -Path 'HKCU:\Accessibility\AudioDescription'**

note **HKCU** stands for **HKEY_CURRENT_USER**, each root is abbreviated intuitively the same way (e.g. **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT** = **HKCR:\**, etc)