# How to delete a .dll that plugs into Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, file, powershell, dll

I installed DAEMON Tools Pro Advanced 5, and I want to uninstall it. The problem with trying this is that it uses an explorer plugin, that creates a Dropbox-like menu in the sidebar of Windows Explorer. I tried running the uninstaller, and it got 50% of the way through, then Windows 10 told me the app was incompatible with my PC.

So I went to my `E:\` drive and tried to delete the files, but it told me that `DTShl64.dll` was in use by Windows Explorer so I can't delete it. I opened up PowerShell as admin and typed `cd E:\` followed by `rmdir /s '.\DAEMON Tools Pro Advanced`, but this is the output:

```
rmdir : Cannot remove item E:\DAEMON Tools Pro Advanced\DTShl64.dll:
Access to the path 'DTShl64.dll' is denied. At line:1 char:1
+ rmdir '.\DAEMON Tools Pro Advanced\'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (DTShl64.dll:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
rmdir : Directory E:\DAEMON Tools Pro Advanced\ cannot be removed
because it is not empty. At line:1 char:1
+ rmdir '.\DAEMON Tools Pro Advanced\'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (E:\DAEMON Tools Pro Advanced\:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotEmpty,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Anyone know a way I can bypass it? Is there some /f token to force it?

Comment: explorer has a handle on it, so try quit explorer first, i.e. `Stop-Process -Name explorer ; Remove-Item -Path "E:\DAEMON Tools Pro Advanced" -Recurse ; Start-Process explorer.exe`

Comment: You will most likely have to clean up the registry as well. The explorer plugin is probably loaded through that. Removing the key(s) and restarting explorer should do the trick.

Comment: How would I go about doing that, @Raziel ?

Comment: @HaydenYoung see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25488840/1244910 - as to which key(s) you'll have to remove I don't know. I don't have that product installed.